# Show Google Visualization API within Fancybox (JS pop-up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, google-visualization

So I'm basically trying to embed a Google Visualization chart within a Fancybox (JS pop-up). The chart shows correctly on the page.. but not within the fancybox. Any ideas?

Here's the code i'm using

```
 $(".class").fancybox(function() { 

      drawChart();

 });
```

--- edit ---

```
 $(".view_research").fancybox({

 'onStart'   : drawChart

 });
```

** this edit does not work either, but at least uses one of the arguments allowed by fancybox

The fancybox loading image is displayed when I click the link.. but the actual pop-up never loads.

I should also note that if I remove the Google chart from the page that the pop-up is trying to load, the pop-up loads without a hitch.

Thanks in advance,
Phil

Comment: I couldn't find a fancybox function which takes a function as an argument. http://fancybox.net/ Check again.

Comment: yes that is correct. see my updated answer for an update

Comment: if you are saying that you are loading another URl which actually contains the drawChart() method and relevant divs, may be you can call drawChart() function on document onload event of that document, without calling it through the fancybox function.

Comment: @Manjula very clever idea.. unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this to work you need to:

1. use the `onComplete` option of the fancybox call
2. explicitly specify a width and height style attribute for the div in which the chart will be drawn

It's common enough with gviz for the div to be visible/drawn before trying to put a chart in it, else you can end up with some pretty odd looking charts (not sure what goes on when you try to render a chart in an invisible div..). The onComplete takes care of this. Using the gviz image library is a good workaround for that problem in other cases.

Anyway, here's a working example of using fancybox and gviz (pie chart code taken from [google code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#pie_chart)):

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['piechart']});
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <script>

      function drawVisualization() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
        data.addRows(5);
        data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
        data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
        data.setValue(2, 0, 'Commute');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
        data.setValue(3, 0, 'Watch TV');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
        data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sleep');
        data.setValue(4, 1, 7);
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('data')).draw(data);
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#inline").fancybox({
          'hideOnContentClick': true,
          onComplete: drawVisualization
        });
      });

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="inline" href="#data">Click here to see chart</a>
      <div style="display:none"><div style='height:200px;width:200px' id="data"></div></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `drawChart` function must specifically draw the chart onto the popup created by fancybox, just calling the function inside the callback will not do any good.

Comment: can you provide some code to illustrate what are you talking about? thx